# How to get particular thing from ManyToMany Fields

Tags: django

I am working on web shop app. I need to get single items from m2m field so I can iterate thru it and get single attirbutes like images etc. Appreciate for any help

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='product_pics')

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
             on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
             related_name="order_item")
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem, related_name="orders")
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)



#VIEWS

def cart_items(request):
    all_items = Item.objects.filter(order_item__orders_user=request.user) 
    if all_items.exists():
        context = {
            "items":all_items
        }
        return render(request, "shop/cart.html", context)
    return redirect("profile")


#template loop

for item in items:
    item.image
```

Comment: At first sight it looks like `OrderItem` is the "through" table of the m2m?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem OrderItem is single item, it helps to estimate if items has already been ordered or not, to add quantity and avoid multiplaying the same item in db. Order represents final order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `items` field to use `OrderItem` as the through table, [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)

```
items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, through=OrderItem, related_name="orders")
```

You can then get all items for the latest order for a user like this

```
latest_order = request.user.order_set.latest('start_date')
all_items = latest_order.items.all()
```

Comment: web.OrderItem: (fields.E336) The model is used as an intermediate model by 'web.Order.items', but it does not have a foreign key to 'Order' or 'Item'. :/

Comment: Try replacing `OrderItem.user` with a foreign key to `Order`

Comment: for some reason I receive error that Order is not defined

Comment: You can reference another model by string to get around that `models.ForeignKey('Order')`